# gostbibliography environment

Tags: biblatex

I use [biblatex-gost](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost) package for formatting bibliography.

I use the experimental environment gostbibliography, which provides unnumbered list of references. Is it possible to use the formatting from this environment but still be able to change the bibliography list spacing and numbering with

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{%
\begin{enumerate}[
  label=\arabic*,%
  leftmargin = 0pt,%
  rightmargin = 0pt,%
  itemindent = \parindent,%
  itemsep = 1em,%
  parsep = \bibparsep]}%
{\end{enumerate}}
{\item}

\printbibliography[env=gostbibliography]
```

I want use item formatting provided by `gostbibliography` environment, which removes spacing and numbering of bibliography items, what does not fit me.

Comment: Can you not use the numeric style given by the package?  `\usepackage[style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}` with a regular `\printbibliography`

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? There shouldn't be any.

Comment: BTW, the environment is experimental only from the standpoint of complying with the GOST standard (inconsistencies are possible). As for biblatex, it's an ordinary `bibenvironment`, there is nothing special about it.

Comment: I don't say that there is something special. Am I asking is it possible to use this environment but save the spacing and numbering of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\defbibenvironment{gostbibliography}{%
\begin{enumerate}[
  label=\arabic*,%
  leftmargin = 0pt,%
  rightmargin = 0pt,%
  itemindent = \parindent,%
  itemsep = 1em,%
  parsep = \bibparsep,%
  before = \toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}]}%
{\end{enumerate}}
{\item}
```